# HTML: Link to non-http resource on the same server

Tags: html, href

I am creating a small internet site for my personal stuff. I want to put there a few links to e.g. FTP resources or SVN server.
The important thing is that the FTP server has the same IP address as the page. I don't want to hard-code the address of my site in the link, because I consider this an anti-pattern. Instead, I would like to tell browser that the resource is on the current server, whichever server it is.

Let's say that the current page is `https://example.com/stuff/index.html`. If I create a tag `<a href="/things/index.html">things</a>`, it will lead to `https://example.com/things.index.html`.
However, if I add a protocol identifier to an URL, it won't work. For example, `<a href="ftp:///files/thingies.tar.gz">download</a>` will lead to `ftp:///files/thingies.tar.gz`, not to `ftp://example.com/files/thingies.tar.gz`.

What magic code should I put in the place of question marks:

```
<a href="ftp://???/files/thingies_directory">download thingies</a>
```

---

UPDATE:
I would prefer a client-side solution. My server machine has **very** low processing power and RAM amount.

Comment: Have you tried this? `<a href="/files/thingies.tar.gz">download thingies</a>`

Comment: Are you suggesting to allow download files by http protocol? In fact I do that and it would work with this example. However, I would like to create links to ftp directories or even non-ftp resources, e.g. SVN. (And you  can't upload files by http easily.) I updated the question.

Comment: normally if it is a .gz file the browser simply downloads it with http protocol. If you link to a directory, normally the browser shows the directory content, if there are read permission from the server side.

Comment: @joao_pimentel My friends will be able to upload files by FTP, which AFAIK cannot be done easily with HTML. I also want to create links to other kind of resources, like SVN servers.

Comment: if your friends upload files via ftp you need a ftp server.

Comment: I have an FTP server. I just want to have links to certain resources on my page.

Answer (score 1):

In php (server side language code) if you'd like to forward

```
ftp:///files/thingies.tar.gz
```

to

```
ftp://example.com/files/thingies.tar.gz
```

considering example.com is the domain where your server is hosted, just do

```
echo 'ftp://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'files/thingies.tar.gz';
```

or, in your specific case

```
<a href="ftp://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/files/thingies.tar.gz">download thingies</a>
```

Comment: Good answer, however my server is in fact just a home router with OpenWRT on it. I would like to avoid installing php support on it. I'll update the question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: what is the issue with this? `<a href="/files/thingies.tar.gz">download thingies</a>`